# When does XHR `ontimeout` is possibly called when `timeout` is 0?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

Is there is any conditions that could lead to `ontimeout` triggered when `timeout` is set to 0?

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', '/something', true);

xhr.timeout = 0; // No timeout

xhr.ontimeout = function (e) {
    // Any circumstances to get here?
};

xhr.send(...);
```

Some sort of slow connection? Or very long internal browser connect/read timeout?

I found some users of the site I maintain fall into this problem and want to figure out why.

Comment: Since [_"The default value is 0, which means there is no timeout"_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/timeout) I would assume that `xhr.ontimeout` never fires.

Comment: [`XMLHttpRequest.timeout`](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#the-timeout-attribute): _"**When set to a non-zero value** will cause fetching to terminate after the given time has passed. When the time has passed, the request has not yet completed, and this’s synchronous flag is unset, a timeout event will then be dispatched, or a "TimeoutError" DOMException will be thrown otherwise (for the send() method)."_

Comment: Despite that timeout is set to 0, `ontimeout` is triggered for some users (according to frontend error logs). I want to determine in which cases this can happen that are not described in the docs.

Comment: [This is the actual spec](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org)